# SMTP server response: 550 - currently not permitted to relay 550-through this server

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using php mail() to send email, via SMTP
But when i send mail from example@example.com, I am getting below error,

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550-(ABC-7d3b78ff) [117.98.220.45]:1747 is currently not permitted to relay 550-through this server. Perhaps you have not logged into the pop/imap server 550-in the last 30 minutes or do not have SMTP Authentication turned on in your 550 email client.

Is this issue with my code or should i need to change on server side?

Here is my code :

```
$header .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0";
$header .= "\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$from    = $row["fromid"];
$to      = $row["email_addr"]; // abc@yahoo.com sending to other than same domain mail
$subject = $row["subject"];

mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Comment: What SMTP server are you trying to send through?  Most servers are configured to not allow relaying from users that are not authenticated.

Comment: Whose SMTP server are you using?

Comment: Do NOT turn on relaying on the server. That's suicide. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer to do your mailing - they allow configuring an SMTP username/password trivially. PHP's built-in mail() function does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like PHP on your server is configured to speak to an SMTP server when using `mail()`.  That error message indicates that your SMTP server expects you to either perform direct authentication, or for you to perform a POP-before-SMTP authentication.  If you are on shared hosting, I commend your web hosting provider for being so clever.

As mentioned in the comments [SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/) is a powerful, easy to use mailing library that includes [the ability to perform SMTP authentication](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/smtp-authentication).  Some people also recommend [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [PEAR's Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail), both of which are also able to perform SMTP auth.

Comment: Another option, my preference, that does SMTP authentication is [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.sending.html)

Comment: i am using SMTP : mail.domain.com, hosted by inetrevolution-linux-server @Ates Goral- payne

Comment: Your SMTP server requires authentication.  You need to use a mailing library that supports SMTP authentication.  I linked three of them in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved, by simply adding the follwing line in your php:

```
    ini_set(sendmail_from,'yourmail@abc.com');
```

Thus your code will become:

```
    $header .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0";
    $header .= "\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $from    = $row["fromid"];
    $to      = $row["email_addr"]; // abc@yahoo.com sending to other than same domain mail
    $subject = $row["subject"];

    ini_set(sendmail_from,'yourmail@abc.com');
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
```